# fork() example program. need explanation

Tags: c, fork, system-calls

this is my code. Please have a look. Can you explain the process flow? it is actually a past paper question. But, I frankly don't understand the concept of fork system calls.

```
main()
{
   int i = 1;
   int ret_val= 0;

   while(i <= 5)
   {
      fork();
      if(ret_val == 0) /*child code*/
      {
         printf("in child %d. \n", i);
         exit(0);
      }
      else
      {     /*parent code*/
         i = i+1;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you read [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)?

Comment: `if(ret_val == 0) ` is always true. This code does not really make sense.

Comment: yes. I read it. But, is it only me or the code itself is wrong?

Comment: i think it should be ret_val = fork(); right?

Comment: For nearly all system calls the return value is relevant in one or the other way.  For `fork()` it is in both. You really want to read the man-pages `RETURN VALUE` section.

Comment: What behavior is not as you expected, specify that, or it's not clear what exactly that you don't understand.

Comment: Also it's `int main(void)` at least for any recent version of the C Standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in the core image of your program, you initialise two values, `ret_val`, and `i` which acts as a counter.

From there on, for 5 times, you `fork()` the program, creating another process with the same image (code). At this point I am assuming your code is wrong, because you are using the `ret_val` variable to check if it's the child or parent process, but to do so, you need to assign it the value from `fork()` like this:

```
ret_val = fork();

if (ret_val == 0)
   // do something as child
else
   // parent code here
```

In essence, your code, for 5 times, increments the value of `i` and has each child process display the current value of `i`.

Comment: Yes bro. I was afraid of the same thing. Thank for the info.

Comment: Also `ret_val` should be of type `pid_t`, as that's what `fork()` returns.

Comment: @alk Yes indeed, but if you just want to experiment and not have production code, having it declared as just an `int` is ok. After all in the `glibc` which is what nearly all `gnu/linux` systems use, [it is an int](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Identification.html) Declaring it as a `pid_t` is useful if you want to denote that the value contained will represent a process identification number using the type of the variable.

Comment: @sanjithedward: You want to say "*... did your homework*"? ;-)

Comment: @NlightNFotis: You're the 1st mentioning Linux in the context of this question.

Comment: @alk Yes you are right. I am sometimes fast to assume that you develop C on Linux (the most common unix variant today) as that's what I am most used to. You are correct that that's only an assumption though, and it could very well be an incorrect one at that.

Comment: @sanjithedward: so you could at least upvote and also probably accept this nice guy's answer.

Comment: @alk - actually. you guys are very fast. and i have to wait upto 10 minutes to upvote the answer. Thank you everyone.

Comment: We did our homework (ourselfs) ... ;-) @sanjithedward

Comment: this is not for my homework. i am studying system calls. So, I wanted to understand this rather than munching on the notes.

Comment: Learning also means learning to learn. Be sure one day, you are stuck off-line. Be prepared, to then having to "*munch the notes*" @sanjithedward